# How to update Chromium version on a cloned repository?

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, webdriver-manager

I have the latest version of Chromium installed globally, but right now I'm working on a cloned repository which has in `node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium\win64-756035\chrome-win` folder an older version of Chromium, and because of that I can't run e2e tests. How can I update it? I've tried to run the `webdriver-manager update` command but it doesn't work.

This is the error shown:

````
```E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87
Current browser version is 83.0.4103.0 with binary path C:\Users\.....\Documents\.....\.....\node_modules\puppeteer\.local-chromium\win64-756035\chrome-win\chrome.exe
  (Driver info: chromedriver=87.0.4280.20 (c99e81631faa0b2a448e658c0dbd8311fb04ddbd-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#355}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19041 x86_64)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Each release of `puppeteer` will install a specific version of Chromium in a directory similar to the path you posted.  You can find out which version of Chromium will come with a version of `puppeteer` in [their release notes](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md).

`webdriver-manager update` will try to install the latest available version of the Chromium webdriver, I believe by checking the [catalog of available versions](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/), or more specifically `https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`.  (Today, that's `91.0.4472.101`).  That version almost certainly won't correspond to the exact version of Chromium installed by `puppeteer`.  You need to manually specify which version of the webdriver you want `webdriver-manager` to install by passing the flag `--versions.chrome=x.y.z`.

(My personal problem is that the webdriver catalog linked above does not actually include a webdriver for the release bundled with any of the recent `puppeteer` releases, so I'm sticking with v6.0.0 for now.)